# Creating a fairly primitive Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, curl

We are rolling out one of our services to another service provider in PHP. They have already built the client, it just sends data in a post (no xml/json etc). Our script then processes it and returns an xml string with the response. Also they will need a token authentication system. Because of the fact they are just using cURL to post raw data, I don't think I can use soap/rest/xml-rpc ... can anyone point me to any good tuts etc?

Cheers,

Comment: cURL supports all the formats you listed, it would just be on them to create the proper XML request in the case of SOAP/XML-RPC.  REST depend on the basic concept of POST/PUT/GET/DELETE and would be the easiest.

http://gdp.globus.org/gt4-tutorial/multiplehtml/ch01s02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oauth is  a secure and easy to implement for security solution for tokens. And they have libraires for java, php, python, and pretty much any language you can think of.

Very strange (and backwards) they built a client without an existing service. but the important thing is to document the interface between your two systems, and adhere to it.

David Walsh explains a simple php web service that returns JSOn or XML. 
http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Comment: Thanks eddie. I'm sorry to sound rather stupid, but how do I implement oauth as a server side service? Everything I find is for the client application. Cheers.